# Inverse of $f^{-1}(x)=x^5+2x^3+3x+1$ question

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Let $f$ be a one-to-one function whose inverse function is $f^{-1}(x)=x^5+2x^3+3x+1$.

Compute the value of $x_0$ such that $f(x_0)=1$.
I am confused as to what this question is asking me, particularly since I don't understand the subscript under the $x$ variable.

Comment: Your first sentence is not a sentence. Format your question with $\LaTeX$. I see neither a variable $x$ nor a subscript. Did you draw that graph?

Comment: There is a subscript under the x variable, identical to the knott symbol. I am not sure how to format that symbol in

Comment: Kurt, I deleted the image: it was misbehaving, and now that you've added the description of $f^{-1}$, it's not needed. Is the inverse function still correct?

Comment: the subscript variable 'x' means another variable, it is a little bit confusing, you should write it as $f^{-1}(y)=x^5+...$

Comment: Kurt, the subscript on $x_0$ doesn't really mean much, it's just trying to distinguish $x_0$ from the variable $x$. $x_0$ is a value that satisfies $f(x_0)=1$

Comment: @Yimin: No, writing $f^{-1}(y)=x^5+\dots$ would be absolutely wrong. It's fine as it is.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I see. Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f^{-1}(x)=x^5+2x^3+3x+1$.

$f(f^{-1}(x))=f(x^5+2x^3+3x+1)$.

$f(f^{-1}(x))=x$  as function property
[image]

$x=f(x^5+2x^3+3x+1)$.

$f(x^5+2x^3+3x+1)=x$

$f(x_0)=1$

You can see that $x=1$ so   $x_0=x^5+2x^3+3x+1$

$x_0=1^5+2.1^3+3.1+1=7$

Answer (score 6):

The point of the question is to see whether you understand how $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are related to each other: $$f\big(f^{-1}(x)\big)=x\;,\tag{1}$$ and $$f^{-1}\big(f(x)\big)=x\tag{2}$$ for any $x$. You want to find an $x_0$ such that $f(x_0)=1$. If $f(x_0)=1$, then $$f^{-1}\big(f(x_0)\big)=f^{-1}(1)\;.$$ Now use $(2)$ the formula for $f^{-1}$ that you've been given, and you'll have your $x_0$.

Comment: Thank you, that greatly clarifies it for me.

Answer (score 1):

One way to find the inverse of an equation is to reverse the variables $x$ and $y$ (this corresponds to reflection over the line $y=x$) and then solve the resulting equation for $y$. In this case, you don't need to actually find the inverse, just compute a specific value. If we have
$$
y=x^5+2x^3+3x+1
$$
then we can write the inverse as
$$
x=y^5+2y^3+3y+1
$$
Since this second equation is the inverse of the inverse, it is the original equation $f(x)$. We want to find the $x_0$ such that $f(x_0)=1$. By the identification of $y$ with the function, all we have to do to find $x_0$ is plug in $y=1$.

EDIT: Brian's answer is exactly what I've done, only written with better notation. Use that since it makes that relationships much clearer than hiding it behind another variable $y$.